# Directly adding text into innerHTML without using innerText

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to add string inside `innerHTML` without having to use `innerText`?

like this:

```js
var sentence="<b>hello there</b>";

document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML='<span class="thing"></span>';
document.querySelector(".thing").innerText=sentence;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body>
  <div class="container"></div>
 
  </body>

</html>
```

but without having to use `innerText`,
Maybe the code would look something like this:

```
var sentence="<b>hello there</b>";

document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML='<span class="thing">'+raw(sentence)+'</span>';
```

Comment: It's possible, but not a very good idea IMO. Your first approach is perfect, I thnk (except - use `.textContent` instead of the less-standard and weird `.innerText`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance `innerText` is a very useful property when it comes to preserving white-space and newlines. As such, the only "weird" thing about it is that it was never standardized.

Comment: @connexo He said he was thinking of something like `raw(sentence)` so I thought he meant he wanted to see the plain text as a result, not the HTML markup. @lemonface, is your first snippet producing the output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything seriously wrong with your current approach. If you want to avoid the repetition of creating an element with a particular class and then have to select it again right after you append it, you can consider creating an *element* instead of an HTML string:

```js
var sentence="<b>hello there</b>";

document.querySelector(".container")
  .appendChild(document.createElement('span'))
  .textContent = sentence;
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming OP expects bold text to show up.

Comment: If your interpretation is correct, you can also use `document.querySelector(".container")
  .appendChild(document.createElement('span')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(sentence))`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!
Just for a reference to the future travelers who might stumble upon this Q,
you can first create a temp element and add style and/or class to it like this https://jsfiddle.net/t93v7sa8/1/